# Does final keyword in java show varying effects when applied :- 1) on a primitive 2) on an object?

Tags: c++, constants, final

It appears to me as if :-

when **final** is applied to a primitive it behaves as a pointer to a constant :-

> const (type)* ptr

and when **final** is applied to an obect it behaves as a constant pointer :-

> (type)* const ptr

Comment: What if `final` behaves like `final`? I wouldn't map Java `final` to C++ `const` to find similarities...

Comment: Umm.. You apply it to a *reference* / *pointer* and not the object. And yes, in java, the behaviour is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first point is a misunderstanding.

Primitive variables never behave like pointers - the value of a primitive variable is a primitive.
The value of an object variable is a reference to an object.

`final` applies to variables, not to values, and means that you can't assign a new value to the variable.

If it's a primitive variable, its value remains the same primitive.
If it's an object variable, the variable always refers to the same, possibly mutable, object.

So the behaviour is identical.

Answer (score 1):

Affect is the same.

**You can't change the Basket. Still you can change the fruits inside.**

Forget about pointers and constants, `final` means you cannot reinitialize it, once you declare it `final`.

Objects are not final only references. You can still change the object, but you cannot re-reference it.

Comment: Actually, `final primitive / String` makes the *primitive / String* a compile time constant (and hence *immutable* and hence *thread-safe* and hence *faster* ). `final reference` doesn't bring about same effects. :)